# WordPress multiple resources plugin

Tags: calendar, wordpress, reservation

Looking for recommendations in regards to booking plugin for WordPress with calendar.

Searched around but I was unable to find a booking calendar plugin which supports multiple availability resources.

Example:

> Apr.25
>
> Available: 4

What I am looking for either by hover text or in calendar text.

> Example:
>
> Apr.25
>
> Available:
>
> Large:5
>
> Medium:4
>
> Small:3

Answer (score 0):

### A WordPress Plugin

It seems that [WP Booking Calendar](https://wpbookingcalendar.com/) has the feature you are looking for. It's only available in their "Business Large" version though (260-350 USD) and since I did never use that version I could not test for myself.

However, this is what [their feature description](https://wpbookingcalendar.com/features/) says:

> - Multiple bookings per same FULL dates (not timeslots).
> - Booking several resources per 1 booking process.
> - Capacity of booking Resources. […]
> - Show availability in mouse over tooltip

So in your case, Large / Medium / Small would be resources, and 5 / 4 / 3 would be their availability, limited by an internal capacity per resource and the current bookings.

### Alternatives

[Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/) is in my opinion the best open source resource booking / scheduling software (I made [a detailed analysis](https://edgeryders.eu/t/6629)).

It's a standalone software though, not a WordPress plugin. But since version 2.7.1 it has the "ability to embed a Booked calendar view on an external website" ([source](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/whatsnew)), and that could be your WordPress website. Not sure if that embedded calendar allows booking or if it is view-only, though.